# No display after removing Graphic Card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have a MSI Motherboard on which ATI Radeon 5580 was installed and everything was working fine. Now I wanted to give my graphic card to someone else, but if I remove my Graphic card and use a VGA cable from Monitor to VGA port of my Motherboard, I can't see the display. Instead, I can hear 8 beeps. What could be my problem?

Please Note:

1. I had already given my card, but now since it was not working I have taken back the card for few days. Now I need to search a way so that my motherboard works without graphic card.
2. I have gone to BIOS and set to set GPU settings to INTERNAL. then removed the GC and restarted. Didn't get the display.
3. Tried to reset BIOS through jumpers. Didn't work. No display.

I have Intel® Core™ i5-660 Processor and MSI H55-GD65 Motherboard and corsair 600 W Power supply. My graphic card is ATI Radeon HD 5580

Comment: what motherboard/processor?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Please see now.

Comment: right. The older P series motherboards wouldn't support the onboard graphics. Its also a processor with an onboard GPU - which rules out not having a onboard GPU or having a motherboard that dosen't support it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I can't use this motherboard without a GC?

Comment: No, I'm saying that *that* might not be the reason its not working

Answer (score 4):

The beeps can be looked up in a search engine, the phrase you needed is "beep code". EG `MSI 8 beep code`.

[8 beeps - Display memory read/write failure](http://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/bios-beeps-and-codes) - which means bad video card typically.

Ensure the onboard graphics is enabled in the BIOS (if an option).

Update the BIOS.

Update the chipset drivers.

Buy another card.

Don't give the current card away.

Check the latest [VGA drivers](http://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/where-can-i-download-vga-drivers-and-how-do-i-install-t)

Comment: I have already searched this. what I want to know what to do since I have already given my card. :( Can't find a way for BIOS reset.

Comment: Why doesn't you original post state that... By not including this information, people are searching for things which 1) don't help you  and 2) it's wasted people's time!

Comment: Looks like you are right. My mistake. I have edited the question. Please see now. Thanks.